# JQuery to Reload DIV Layer with PHP GET from Text Box

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, html

Greetings from some noob trying to learn JQuery,

I am attempting to make it when you type something in a box below a div layer it reloads that layer upon submission of the form with a php get of the text box in the form.  Expected behavior is it would reload that box, actual behavior is it don't do anything.  Can someone help me out here.... Below is the code.

```
<div id="currentwxdiv">This is where the new stuff happens
</div>
<form name="changewx" action="/">
<input type="text" id="city">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="New City" /> 
</form>
<script>
  /* attach a submit handler to the form */
  $('form[name="changewx"]').submit(function(event) {


    /* get some values from elements on the page: */
    var $form = $( this ),
        city = $('#city').val()

    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    $('#currentwxdiv').load('http://api.mesodiscussion.com/?location=' + city);
    return false;

  });
</script>
```

Its giving the Javascript Console Error Error....

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.mesodiscussion.com/?location=goodjob. Origin http://weatherofoss.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: This may not solve your problem, but the page you are 'post'ing data to is a directory, not a script. You may want to add either zones.php, current.php, embed.php or untitled.php

Comment: @Ram - I added the current.php - that was an error.  Thanks for pointing that out.  However it did not solve the problem.  It still seems to be doing nothing.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.mesodiscussion.com/?location=goodjob. Origin http://weatherofoss.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using POST method? is impossible to post to an external url because with ajax, the url fails the "[Same Origin POlice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)".

If you use GET method, is possible to do that.

Another solution is to make a proxy. A little script that recive the params and then... using CURL or another thing you have to post to the external URL... finally, you jquery have to do the post thing to the proxy:

For example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/proxy.php?location=' + city,
  success: function(data) {
     $('#currentwxdiv').html(data);

  }
});
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I do it so:

```
    <div id="currentwxdiv">This is where the new stuff happens
    </div>
    <form name="changewx" action="/">
    <input type="text" id="city">

    </form>
    <script>

$('#city').keyup(function() {
var city = $('#city').val() 

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://api.mesodiscussion.com/?location=' + city,
  success: function(data) {
     $('#currentwxdiv').html(data);

  }
});



});

    </script>
```

Comment: I would try adding to the ajax function. data: "&location=" +city   and removing it from post url

Comment: try it:   **var city = $('#city').val();**

Answer (score 0):

To help you out, i need to test this. 
What's the url address of your html code working ?

http://api.mesodiscussion.com/?location= doesn't work... only list the directory content... maybe that's de problem?

Greatings.